# Некорректный вывод sfc при его переопределении

Tags: c#, консоль, cmd

При переопределении вывода команды "sfc /scannow" ломается ее вывод. По стандарту вывод в консоли идет 1%..100%, но при переопределении первое уведомление чаще всего происходит на 46% причем сразу приходит большое количество прошлых уведомлений - 1%..46%. Затем снова молчание и опять уведомления на 91% и на 100%. Причем это происходит именно на "sfc /scannow". Другая команда "ping ya.ru -t" работает корректно.

Хотелось бы как-то уведомлять пользователя о прогрессе, а не ждать примерно минуту до 46%, а затем еще минуту и сразу 91%,100% и финальный вывод...

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    ProcessStartInfo proc = new()
    {
        FileName = "sfc",
        Arguments = "/scannow",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    };

    Process process = new()
    {
        StartInfo = proc
    };

    process.Start();
    process.OutputDataReceived += Process_OutputDataReceived;
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    await process.WaitForExitAsync();

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void Process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data) && e.Data != "\0")
    {             
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
}
```

Но если поменять команду на другую, то вывод работает коректно.

```
ProcessStartInfo proc = new()
{
    FileName = "ping",
    Arguments = "ya.ru -t",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема кроется в том как перенаправляется поток из stdout.

Делается это через пайпы которые имеют буферизацию (например в вашем случае это 4кб) и если запускаемый процесс не позаботился о сбросе буфера, то придеётся ждать его переполнения или завершения процесса (вот более развёрнутый ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503671/python-c-program-subprocess-hangs-at-for-line-in-iter )

Для решения проблемы можно попробовать запускать процесс через т.н. псевдо терминал - pty.
Для .net я видел только одну реализацию и она не имеет пакета в nuget, это Pty.Net (https://github.com/microsoft/vs-pty.net )

Comment: Спасибо за информацию! Я уже отчался( 
Только из вашего ответа мне непонятен один момент. Если буфер фиксированный, то почему каждый раз происходит переполнение на разном этапе(42-51%), ведь количество текста всегда одинаковое, т.к запускаю на одной и той же машине с одним состоянием. Т.е есть какая-то погрешность. В любом случае буду разбираться!

Comment: @Lapish чтобы ответить на этот вопрос надо смотреть в исходниках, которых у нас нет )